# How can I send carbon copies to the same recipient in every step of the signing process?

Tags: c#, docusignapi

We require two signers and one carbon copy recipient which receives a carbon copy for every status change of the signing process.

Using DocuSign.eSign [Nuget package 2.1.4](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocuSign.eSign.dll/2.1.4), I tried:

1. adding the carbon copy recipient (RecipientId=1)
2. adding the first signer (RecipientId=2)
3. adding the same carbon copy recipient as in step 1 (RecipientId=1)
4. adding the second signer (RecipientId=3)
5. adding the same carbon copy recipient as in step 1 (RecipientId=1)

I'm increasing RoutingOrder along the way (from 1 to 5)
A recipient simply contains values for: Email, Name, RecipientId and RoutingOrder, nothing more.

This, however causes the API to return

> ENVELOPE_HAS_DUPLICATE_RECIPIENTS.

I tried to find a solution for this in the [documentation](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipients/), but can't seem to find the correct paragraph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the [DocuSign c# SDK](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-csharp-client), then the following code should accomplish what you are trying. See full example [here](https://gist.github.com/codingdawg/46e72ae035a0c871ef558531f3efff58).

The envelope has the recipients in the following order

1. CC Recipient (janecc@acme.com)
2. Signer (janedoe@acme.com)
3. CC Recipient (janecc@acme.com)
4. Signer (bobbydoe@acme.com)
5. CC Recipient (janecc@acme.com)

   ```
   public void CreateEnvelopeDuplicateRecipients()
   {
       string accountID = "";//Initialization code here.

       byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\temp\test.pdf");
       var envDef = new EnvelopeDefinition()
       {
           EmailSubject = "Envelope with CC & Signers",
           Status = "Sent",

           Documents = new List<Document>()
           {
               new Document()
               {
                   DocumentBase64 = System.Convert.ToBase64String(fileBytes),
                   Name = "Dummy",
                   DocumentId = "1"
               }
           },
           Recipients = new Recipients()
           {
               CarbonCopies = new List<CarbonCopy>()
               {
                   new CarbonCopy()
                   {
                       Email = "janecc@acme.com",
                       Name = "jane cc",
                       RecipientId = "1",
                       RoutingOrder = "1"
                   },
                   new CarbonCopy()
                   {
                       Email = "janecc@acme.com",
                       Name = "jane cc",
                       RecipientId = "3",
                       RoutingOrder = "3"
                   },
                   new CarbonCopy()
                   {
                       Email = "janecc@acme.com",
                       Name = "jane cc",
                       RecipientId = "5",
                       RoutingOrder = "5"
                   }
               },
               Signers = new List<Signer>()
               {
                    new Signer()
                    {
                         Email = "janedoe@acme.com",
                         Name = "jane doe",
                         RecipientId = "2",
                         RoutingOrder = "2",
                         Tabs = new Tabs()
                         {
                             SignHereTabs = new List<SignHere>()
                             {
                                 new SignHere()
                                 {
                                   DocumentId = "1", XPosition = "100", YPosition = "200", PageNumber = "1",
                                 }
                             }
                         }
                    },
                     new Signer()
                    {
                         Email = "bobbydoe@acme.com",
                         Name = "bobbydoe Demo",
                         RecipientId = "4",
                         RoutingOrder = "4",
                         Tabs = new Tabs()
                         {
                             SignHereTabs = new List<SignHere>()
                             {
                                 new SignHere()
                                 {
                                   DocumentId = "1", XPosition = "100", YPosition = "300", PageNumber = "1",
                                 }
                             }
                         }
                    }
               }
           }
       };

       var envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi();
       EnvelopeSummary envelopeSummary = envelopesApi.CreateEnvelope(accountID, envDef);
       Console.WriteLine(envelopeSummary);
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks for sharing CodingDawg, the answer was in the RecipientId.
I used a unique RecipientId per email address, because I thought it is meant as an identifier for a specific recipient. This caused me to use the same RecipientId multiple times and that triggered the error message.